# PHP - Sequence through array and repeat [modulo-operator]

Tags: php, arrays, loops, sequence

I need to be able to loop an array of items and give them a value from another array and I cant quite get my head around it.

**My Array**

```
$myarray = array('a','b','c');
```

Lets say I have a foreach loop and I loop through 6 items in total.

How do I get the following output

```
item1 = a
item2 = b
item3 = c
item4 = a
item5 = b
item6 = c
```

My code looks something like this.

```
$myarray = array('a','b','c'); 
$items = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6);
foreach ($items as $item) {
   echo $myarray[$item];
}
```

Online example.
http://codepad.viper-7.com/V6P238

I want to of course be able to loop through an infinite amount of times

Comment: use a foreach loop nested in a for loop, run the for loop for as long as you want it to run

Comment: Use a `for` loop. Additionally, what have you tried?

Comment: ive tried a for loop and i obviously get stuck every I reach item 4, as there is no corresponding key/value in $myarray

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$myarray = array('a','b','c'); 
$count = count($myarray);
foreach ($array as $index => $value) {
  echo $value . ' = ' . $myarray[$index % $count] . "\n";
}
```

`%` is the [modulo-operator](http://php.net/language.operators.arithmetic). It returns

> Remainder of $a divided by $b.

what means

```
0 % 3 = 0
1 % 3 = 1
2 % 3 = 2
3 % 3 = 0
4 % 3 = 1
```

and so on. In our case this reflects the indices of the array `$myarray`, that we want to retrieve.

Comment: Why `$index % $count` if you're only doing one `foreach` anyway? It's still the same as `$index`.

Comment: @Palladium No, it isn't. `$index` is the index of the current `$value`, whereas `$count` is a static value.

Comment: Yes it is. `$index`, being defined as the numeric keys of the elements, will never be higher than `$count` (given his test array). Your cases of `3%3` and `4%3` will never happen in your `foreach` loop.

Comment: @Palladium In his example the OPs speaks from an array with size 6 items in `$array` (in his edit he called it `$items`), but `$myarray` is of size 3, thus _it will happen_.

Comment: @Palladium The sentence "Lets say I have a foreach loop and I loop through 6 items in total." stands there right from the beginning ....

Comment: But he also said "of course I want to loop through it infinitely". His words, my paraphrasing, but you get the idea. I assumed he was somehow confusing himself when he wanted to just print `a,b,c,a,b,c,...` an arbitrary number of times.

Comment: Hey guys thank you all for your answers. I accepted this one as it had some more explanation and its fits my criteria, thank you.

Comment: @Palladium Oh, ok, I see. In this case you can replace the `foreach`-statement with `for ($index = 0; true; $index++)` and the loop body is valid again :) (until it reaches `PHP_INT_MAX`? :X). Enough for now :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want an arbitrary number of loops to be done, you can use the modulus operator to cycle through your keys:

```
$loop = //how much you want the loop to go
//...
for ($i = 0, $i < $loop, $i++) {
    $key = $i % count($myarray);
    echo $i, ' = ', $myarray[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). Try something like this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $NUMBER_OF_ITEMS; $i++) {
    echo "item$i = ".$myarray[$i % count($myarray)]."\n";
}
```